# OpenGL Textures: how do I create an image path?

Tags: c++, stb-image

I'm stuck trying to upload textures here:

```
// The FileSystem::getPath(...) is part of the GitHub repository so we can find files on any IDE/platform; replace it with your own image path.
    unsigned char *data = stbi_load(FileSystem::getPath("resources/textures/container.jpg").c_str(), &width, &height, &nrChannels, 0);
```

In regards to the comment above, how do I replace it with my own image path? I tried something like this:

```
unsigned char *data = stbi_load("Desktop/container.jpg").c_str(), &width, &height, &nrChannels, 0);
```

But it didn't work, of course, my little brain is overloaded right now and I just can't think straight. So... *how do I specify an image path?*

*UPDATE: this is the error message I'm getting:*
[image]

Comment: I would assume you either need the _full_ path eg `/home/$USER/Desktop/container.jpg` or, likely the better solution, move the file into the correct project directory so the relative path will work.

Comment: Assuming `Desktop/container.jpg` is the correct and accessible file name then just use `stbi_load("Desktop/container.jpg", &width, &height, &nrChannels, 0)` -- `c_str()` is a member of whatever type is returned by `FileSystem::getPath` .

Comment: Hey Joshua, the error that I'm getting is: FileSystem::GetPath these two are in red. 'FileSystem' is not a class or namespace  and 'getPath' identifier not found

Comment: Hey G.M, still nothing :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the fix: It was indeed as Joshua said, "move the file into the correct project directory so the relative path will work". So in my project I created a folder called 'Textures' and added the textures there, and I called the texture using:

```
unsigned char* data = stbi_load("Textures/container.jpg", &width, &height, &nrChannels, 0);
```

I would like to close this post by adding Joshua's answer as the correct one but Idk how to do it so I'll add this one thx everybody for the help and insight